# How to push my local commit when my github have another commit and i forgot to pull my commit in github

Tags: android, git, github

Hi i'm here to asking you, **how to push my commit/chage(s) when i have another commit and i forgot to pull the commit from github.**
This is the *chronology*: when i'm no have another work, i decide to make own project and i use *git* to be my vcs, and then i make my project to be repository.
A few day's later, i decide to *remoting* my github.
Everything is alright until the problem come. In one day, i'm edit my *README.md* and save the change, in git same to but a different is i updating my *source code* and save the change. After that i'm push my commit and this is happent.
[Screen shoted the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHaei.jpg)
But in here, i'm not realize **i'm forgot to pull a commit from github** until i'm realized that.

So please help me! I stuck in this condition! Please!
And i'm sorry if my English is bad

Comment: You can pull changes from remote then push . Better take a backup if you are not confident .

Comment: I'm was do that, but fail! I don't how to method

Comment: what error are you getting when you pull the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically your solution might be to pull the changes from GitHub (that is, if I understand correctly you have did some changes to you remote Github - updated your README.md - not from your local - now you want that change to be reflected in your local and you need to push your new changes in the local to the remote).
The best solution would be to first add all your changes to staging and then committing by doing:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message (One-liner of your change)"
```

and then do a rebase as follows:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Rebasing will pull the changes from the remote, and re-apply your local changes on top of it, thus your local repo is now in sync with the remote repo (they are essentially in the same state). Now you can do the push:

```
git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

Comment: Push to main branch would be as: git push -u origin master